# Can't install anything with Conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I keep getting the following error when I try to install or update modules with Conda. Any help?

I install using the following commands (basically any installation or upgrade command):

```
conda install tensorflow
conda install numpy
```

And this is the error message:

> Fetching package metadata ... CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION
>   FAILED for url 
>   Elapsed: -
>
> An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL. HTTP errors
>   are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
>
> ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org',
>   port= 443): Max retries exceeded with url:
>   /simple/win-64/repodata.json (Caused by New
>   ConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
>   11004] getaddrinfo fail ed',))",),)

Also pip is not able to install any modules either. It keeps saying:

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection : [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/

Comment: Can you give us more details about the command line you used?

Comment: Yes! C:\... conda install tensorflow or conda install numpy... Basically any installation or upgrade command. Also pip is not able to install any modules either...keeps saying:   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
 after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTT
PSConnection object at 0x0000000005DBB7B8>: Failed to establish a new connection
: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/tensorflow/

Comment: Are you behind some firewall? Have you tried to load `pypi.python.org` directly in a web browser?

Comment: Try `conda install -c anaconda numpy` and `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Comment: I can access pypi.python.org if i type it into the web browser. What's weird about this, is that have installed and uninstalled python a couple of times. I was trying to get some stuff fix, but i see that i just made it worse. During these cycles i tried to venture on my own and delete some files in the C drive. Maybe i deleted something i shouldn't. The problem is, that i started getting this error after the last time in installed it (which i assumed it was going to fix any delete file problems). trying "conda install -c conda" also give the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you installed Anaconda on a work computer behind a firewall. I had the same issues after installing it on my work laptop too, but no problems at all with the installation on my personal laptop at home. Please see this answer for setting up a .condarc config file in your home directory which is typically c:\users[your user id].

The answer addresses both config entries for proxy servers and ssl verification.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621792/5745815