# Unable to use Conda with Anaconda 2018.2 on Windows

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I just did a fresh installation of Anaconda 2018.2 on Windows 10. This anaconda version uses python v3.7. While running conda for updating `conda update conda`, I got the following error;

```
Collecting package metadata: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. I discovered 2 solutions.

First solution is to use Anaconda Prompt

Second solution is to install OpenSSL for Windows. The binaries can be downloaded here;

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

This binary worked for me. https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-1_1_1a.exe
I am running 64-bit Windows 10.

Above solutions have been tested to work on my PC.

Answer (score 12):

What worked for me was to copy these files from Anaconda3/Library/bin to Anaconda3/DLLs :

libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll

libssl-1_1-x64.dll

Comment: libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
libssl-1_1-x64.dll

two files haven't been updated in my case, compare dates in both folders and update if nesseccary

Comment: i saw the same answer here https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9003 and it has worked as well

Answer (score 5):

Using Anaconda Prompt as Administrator worked for me. I have not tried the second solution (OpenSSL)

Comment: Simple but effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem running conda on my work laptop behind a firewall. Create a .condarc config file in your home directory, typically 'c:\users\[your user id]', if one doesn't already exist. Add an entry to turn off SSL verification. Looks like this:

```
ssl_verify:  false
```

Save the file and retry the conda command.

If this doesn't work and your computer is behind a firewall. Make sure the proxy server entries are also defined in the .condarc config file. Example:

```
proxy_servers:
   http: http://www.proxy.com:8080
   https: https://www.proxy.com:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<anaconda_or_miniconda_installation_directory>\Library\bin` to the `PATH` environment variable is sufficient to solve this problem.